# Compound index and query to a single column: do I need an index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a table `SchoolMembers`, and it has two columns:

```
  person_id   school_id
 -------------------------
    1134       361
    1135       362
         ...
```

The primary key of this table is `{person_id, school_id}`, so this combination is unique.

The primary key is indexed wih an index called `PK_dbo.SchoolMembers`

- `person_id` doesn't have an INDEX
- `school_id` doesn't have an INDEX
- `{person_id, school_id}` has an INDEX

Question: if I have this query:

```
     SELECT * from SchoolMembers where person_id = 1135
```

...should I have an INDEX for `person_id`? I need the previous query to be fast

Comment: When in doubt, include the actual execution plan, run the query, and see for yourself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Question: if I have this query:
> `SELECT * from SchoolMembers where person_id = 1135`
> ...should I have an INDEX for person_id?

No. The unique index on {person_id, school_id} is sufficient.  In general an index can be used for efficient access by its leading column(s).

This query will start with a BTree seek to the first leaf page containing a row with person_id = 1135.  Each leaf page has a forward and backward page pointer to the next and previous page in the index order.  The plan will then scan the leaf pages until it has read all the school_id values for that person_id.

Answer (score 4):

The order of the columns of the primary key make a difference. You've described your key as being by `person_id` then `school_id`. With that setup, you should get good performance when searching on `person_id`. However the opposite is NOT true. If you were to search by `school_id`, it would not be able to quickly find that row.